# Databricks Notebook Cell Runtime

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

**Is there a way to fetch runtime of a particular cell in data bricks Notebook using Pyspark?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import time
start = time.time()

time.sleep(3)
end = time.time()
diff=end - start
print(diff)
```

I was able to achieve my requirement with above code

Comment: Glad to know that your issue has resolved. After 48 hours, you can [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by calling System.nanoTime (Scala). When using Spark with Scala, a way to execute code and measure its elapsed time is by using: spark.time(

**Note:** You can use the run multiple languages in the notebooks using %magic commands.

[image]

OR

[image]

Comment: when i run the above code snippet, i am getting a single result eerytime (7.0.x-scala2.12). How can i identify the time taken?

Comment: Entire notebooks cells are bound to the single runtime which is associated with the attached Cluster. If you change the cluster associated with notebook, you will see the runtime version of the attached cluster.

Comment: got your point, but i need to store run time taken by a particular cell in a variable and reuse. how can i achieve this requirement.

Comment: Sorry I have misunderstood the question incorrect. I thought you want to get the Azure Databricks Runtime and not the execution time of the cell. Here are the couple of ways to get the execution time(you can do this by calling System.nanoTime (Scala) or time.time() (Python). When using Spark with Scala, a way to execute code and measure its elapsed time is by using: spark.time(<code to measure>).